# SSIS Package Executes With Errors When Executing from C# Application

Tags: c#, ssis

We have an SSIS package that executes perfectly when run from BI on our server.

We have a client application that calls a service on the server, and the service being called, executes the SSIS package.

This package executes fine in BI with no errors. The package generates some PDF files, and then uses PDFSharp to combine those PDF files so that we can later email the single PDF file. The package also inserts some records into a database table so that we can keep track of these files that was generated.

However, once the client application calls the service to execute the SSIS package, we are greeted with these error messages:

[image]

Does anyone know why we are getting these error messages?

The code the service uses to execute this SSIS package is the following C# code:

```
                //Get the package's information from the database.
                List<SSISPackage> lsSSISPackages = MatchDataTableToTypeProperties<SSISPackage>(dt);

                SSISPackage package = lsSSISPackages.FirstOrDefault();
                string packageLocation = $"{package.Path}/{package.Name}";

                Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
                DtsEventListeners eventListener = new DtsEventListeners();
                Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(packageLocation, eventListener);

                //Get and set parameters.
                string[] arrParameters = package.Parameters.Split(',');
                foreach (string parameter in arrParameters)
                {
                    var param = pkg.Parameters.Add(parameter, TypeCode.Int32);
                    param.Value = 1;
                }

                try
                {
                    DTSExecResult pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, null, eventListener, null, null);

                    string errors = eventListener.Errors;

                    MessageBox.Show($"Execution result: {errors}");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                }
```

Now, the DtsEventListeners class, which is used to catch errors from the SSIS package, looks like this:

```
public class DtsEventListeners : DefaultEvents
{
    public string Errors { get; set; }

    public override bool OnError(DtsObject source, int errorCode, string subComponent,
    string description, string helpFile, int helpContext, string idofInterfaceWithError)
    {
        // Add application-specific diagnostics here.
        string err = $"Error in {source}/{subComponent} : {description}";
        Errors += $"{err}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}";
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I cannot, for the life of me, see why this fails from the C# service side. I have no idea why this fails, and no idea how to resolve it.

If anyone has an idea, your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing pdfsharp is something you have installed on your BI server? if so, it's missing from the server where you're running that service

Comment: But running it from BI on the same server works fine... the PdfSharp DLLs lives in this directory on the server: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn" Should it live in the service's directory?

Comment: basically the error code is clearly telling you it can't load it; so you will have to look at your project's setup to make sure it can load that dll; could be permissions, could be as simple as sticking it as a nuget dependency on the service (i.e. it will be included in the build output of the service)

Comment: That does not seem to be the problem. The errors seems to be misleading here. I created a stored procedure which will execute the SSIS Package, and all seems to be working fine now. I don't know why this fails using C#, but using the stored procedure way is fine with me - I'm happy with it. Thanks though!

Comment: that is definitely the problem; the sql server agent and the c# stuff run under different accounts with different privileges, etc if you've found a way that works for you then cool